# Would it be possible to convert a NodeJS function to plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

Im currently playing with the following thing: http://cgbystrom.com/articles/deconstructing-spotifys-builtin-http-server/, I want to be able to access the SpotifyWebHelper with Javascript, people have build this in NodeJS but I wonder if this is possible in plain JavaScript. Can anyone give me some pointers to start with? Or is this not possible at all?

NodeJS version:
https://github.com/onetune/spotify-web-helper/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Node **is** JavaScript, this question makes no sense.

Comment: The whole point of the security features described in that post is to prevent you from doing this from a web page.

Answer (score 3):

Node.js is "plain Javascript", the only difference between Node.js and everything else is it has access to the actual computer instead of being trapped in a web sandbox.

If you mean "can I make this work in a browser?" the answer is no. It needs to be able to spawn processes, which you can't do in a browser.